# Why do I not need to escape a Regex character if it is read from console in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Please see the following programs:

**UseArgs.java**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class UseArgs {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String foo = args[0];
        String bar = args[1];

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(foo);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(bar);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.print("Found at index: " + m.start() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**UseConsole.java**

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.Console;

class UseConsole {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Console console = System.console();

        String foo = console.readLine("foo: ");
        String bar = console.readLine("bar: ");

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(foo);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(bar);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.print("Found at index: " + m.start() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

So in order to work with UseArgs I need to call the program as follows:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ java UseArgs \\d 4
Found at index: 0
```

but for **UseConsole**, please see how I do **not** need to escape "any digit" character:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ java UseConsole
foo: \d
bar: 4
Found at index: 0
```

What is the reason behind the difference in the behaviours? I tried, but could not find any documentation, why we do **not** need to escape when the expression is read using the Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "call" your program from the command prompt, you provide input to another running program - a "shell program" of your operating system.

Shells have their own syntax rules. In particular, they use backslash as an escape character. Hence, the input that you want to pass to your Java program is first used as an input to shell program; your Java program gets the output of shell's transformation of that input.

Among other things, shell interprets all single backslashes as escape characters, stripping them from the strings that it passes to your Java program (or any other program, for that matter). That is why end-users must escape individual slashes when entering them on the command line.

Similar process is in play when you hard-code a regex in your Java code. This time, the compiler is doing the stripping of backslashes, using slightly stricter rules (unlike most shells, Java errors out on "stray" backslashes in string literals, rather than throwing them out).

In contrast, the input that you read from the console does not go through any transformation. Your program is the first one to get the input, so no backslash escaping is necessary.

Comment: But what is more interesting is,I also need to escape if I have a `String anyDigitPattern = "\\d";` in the source code. Weird!

Comment: @KorayTugay That's not even closely related to "weird". `\d` is not a valid [escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) so you obviously need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

To show this difference better, let's add a print statement in 2nd program:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.Console;
class UseConsole {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Console console = System.console();

        String foo = console.readLine("foo: ");    
        System.out.printf("<%s> <%s>%n", foo, args[0]);

        String bar = console.readLine("bar: ");    
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(foo);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(bar);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.print("Found at index: " + m.start() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And run you program as:

```
java -cp . UseConsole \d
```

Following output will be printed when you type `\d` next to `foo:` prompt:

```
foo: \d
<\d> <d>
bar: ab12
Found at index: 2
Found at index: 3
```

Note the difference between `<\d>` and `<d>`. So the command line argument of `\d` became just plain `d` inside the program because of shell eating away a backslash since backslash is special construct for shell to escape any character. Shell doesn't interpret it if you quote the arguments:

```
java -cp . UseConsole "\d"
```

That will print:

```
<\d> <\d>
```

Note how `\d` is being interpreted correctly inside the Java program now.

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments are first interpreted by the shell,
before passing to the executable program.
They are subject to variable expansion, glob expansion,
to give just a few examples.
The `\` character has a special meaning in the shell,
so if you want to pass a literal `\` as part of an argument,
you need to escape it, like you did.

When you enter input on the `stdin` processed by a program,
there is no shell in the middle to interpret that.
Your keystrokes should go directly on the input stream.
That's why you don't need to escape them in that case.

Comment: But what is more interesting is,I also need to escape if I have a `String anyDigitPattern = "\\d";` in the source code. Weird!

Comment: @KorayTugay just as `\` has a special meaning in the shell, it has a special meaning in string literals in Java. Since `\` is widely used as an escape character in software and tools, I don't find this behavior surprising at all.

Comment: and seems like  \ also works as an escape character in code formatted text like in `\\` n this forum

Comment: Finally I got the syntax right for SE comments :-) ->  just as ``\`` has a special meaning in the shell, it has a special meaning in string literals in Java. Since ``\`` is widely used as an escape character in software and tools, I don't find this behavior surprising at all.